# Netbeans and apache tomcat

Tags: netbeans, tomcat

Is there a direct way to deploy a `netbeans` project, where `springframe` work has been used, in `apache tomcat server`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. All you need to do is to register the server and make it the default server for your project.

**From the NetBeans online help:**

*Registering a Server*

Before you can deploy an enterprise application, web application, JSP file, servlet, or EJB module, the server to which you are going to deploy needs to be registered with the IDE.

To register an external server:

- Choose Tools > Servers in the main menu.
- In the Server Manager, click Add Server.
- The Add Server wizard appears and displays the types of servers that are compatible with the IDE.
- In the dialog box, select the type of server you want to register and click Next.
  Specify the server-specific information in the panels that follow and click Finish.

*Changing the Target Server*

Each project has a target server. The target server is the server that is used when the project is run. You can set the target server to any server which has been registered in the IDE.

To change the target server:

- Right-click the project node in the Projects window and choose Properties.
- Select Run in the Project Properties dialog box.
- Select the new target server from the Server drop-down menu and click OK.